# Javascript Imports a single bootsrap JS file

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

Is it possible to create a bootsrap JS file to Import files?

E.g

`Bootsrap.js`
I want to have all my JS `imports` to be handled by this file and like the `__autoload()` in `PHP`

so in my Index.js, I want to `import Bootstrap from './Imports';`

Then call any `Constant` or `Variable` imported by the `Bootstrap.js` file in my `Index.js` anytime

e.g `<View/>`, `<Text>My text</Text>` anywhere in my `Index.js`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not possible to do this natively, at least not yet.

It has been a planned feature for some time though, at least [according to this source](http://2ality.com/2014/09/es6-modules-final.html).

> The module loader API has various hooks for configuration. It is still work in progress. A first system loader for browsers is currently being implemented and tested. The goal is to figure out how to best make module loading configurable.
>
> The loader API will permit many customizations of the loading process. For example:
>
> 1. Lint modules on import (e.g. via JSLint or JSHint).
> 2. Automatically translate modules on import (they could contain CoffeeScript or TypeScript code).
> 3. Use legacy modules (AMD, Node.js).
>
> Configurable module loading is an area where Node.js and CommonJS are limited.

AFAIK, there hasn't been much progress on this yet.